# Windows 8 app development. An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: wcf

Whats wrong with this:

```
1-MyServiceReference.ServiceClient client = new MyServiceReference.ServiceClient();
2-MyServiceReference.User temp = await client.VerifyUser(user_email.Text);
```

it gives me the following Exception at line 2:
"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to {Service Url}. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details".

Comment: Did you look at the server logs?

Comment: @tim No. this is working perfect for windows phone but exception occure in windows 8.